# React : Get value of table to edit it

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I've a form with fields. When i submit this form, I complete my bootstrap table with fields values

I want to call this form for each row, and get values by table on form to edit its.

I call the form empty, without values. How can I call the form with values by reference ?

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.props.items} cellEdit={this.cellEdit}>
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='reference' dataFormat={this.editFormatter.bind(this)}>Edit</TableHeaderColumn</BootstrapTable>

editFormatter(cell, row) {
    return (
        <button onClick={() => this.editFormatterClick = (reference: string) => { }}>{cell}</button>
    );

}

editFormatterClick = (reference:string) => {        
    this.props.onDocumentSelected(reference)
}

onDocumentSelected: (documentReference: string) => void
```

This property onDocumentSelected call the form. How can i call this form with values by list ? 
Thank you

Comment: Are you using JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, i'm using javascript in React

Comment: Why are you defining the type for each function parameter?